# Как подсчитать сумму всех ячеек в таблице, при условии что количество единиц меняется и от этого меняется цена одной ячейки?

Tags: angularjs, uikit

app.js

```
angular
    .module('app',[])
    .controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
        $http.get('price.json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.posts = data;
        })          
        $scope.val = 1;
        $scope.kurs = 21;
        $scope.check = true;
        $scope.all = {};
    }
);

angular
    .module('app')
    .filter('total', function() {
        return function(price) {
            var newprice = {};
            var result = 0;
            for (var key in price) {
                newprice = price[key].replace(',', '');
                result += parseFloat(newprice.replace(',', ''));
            }
            result = String(result).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
            return result;
        };
    });
```

index.html

```
  <div class="uk-margin-large-top" ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
    <div class="uk-text-right">Быстрый поиск по слову или фразе
      <input type="text" placeholder="демонтаж" ng-model="query" />
    </div>
    <table class="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="uk-text-center">№</th>
          <th>Наименование работ</th>
          <th class="uk-text-center">Ед. изм.</th>
          <th>Цена</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="price in posts | filter:query">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="4">
            <h2>{{ price.category }}</h2>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="datafields in price.datafields | filter:query">
          <td class="{{check}}">
            <input ng-model="check" type="checkbox" /> {{$index + 1}}</td>
          <td class="{{check}}">{{ datafields.name }}</td>
          <td class="{{check}}">
            <input ng-model="val" ng-disabled="!check" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" class="{{check}} number-pole" value="1" type="number" /> {{ datafields.ed }}</td>
          <td class="{{ all[datafields.name] = (check) ? (datafields.cost * kurs * val | number: 0) : zero }} 
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th style="border: 0" colspan="2"></th>
          <th colspan="2">
            <br /> Общая сумма: <h2>{{ all | total | number: 3 }}</h2></th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
```

[ссылка на Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6pVY1oCm5SQcvFwjSmLJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил следующим образом:

HTML

```
  <div class="uk-margin-large-top" ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
    <div class="uk-text-right">Быстрый поиск по слову или фразе
      <input type="text" placeholder="демонтаж" ng-model="query" />
    </div>
    <table class="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="uk-text-center">№</th>
          <th>Наименование работ</th>
          <th>Ед. изм.</th>
          <th>Цена</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="price in posts | filter:query">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="5">
            <h2>{{ price.category }}</h2></th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="datafields in price.datafields | filter:query" ng-init="init(i, $last);">
          <td class="uk-text-right">{{$index + 1}}</td>
          <td>{{datafields.name}}</td>
          <td>
            <input ng-init="inputInit($parent.$index, $index, $parent.$last, datafields.cost*kurs)" ng-change="valChange($parent.$index, $index)" ng-model="val[$parent.$index][$index].cout" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" class="uk-text-center number-pole" value="0" type="number">
            <span class="ed">{{ datafields.ed }}</span>
          </td>
          <td class="uk-width-2-10">
            <div class="costInt">{{ datafields.cost * val[$parent.$index][$index].cout * kurs | round | number : 0 }}<span class="rub"> руб</span></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th style="border: 0" colspan="2"></th>
          <th colspan="2">
            <br>Общая сумма:
            <h2>{{ getSumm() | total }} руб. </h2>
            <button class="uk-button uk-button-danger" ng-click="reset();"><i class="uk-icon-eraser"></i> Сбросить</button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
```

JS

```
(function() {

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller("PostsCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {

      $http.get('price.json').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.posts = data;
      });

      $scope.val = {};
      $scope.kurs = 21000;

      $scope.inputInit = function(parentI, i, last, cost) {
        var identy = 'Numb' + parentI + '_' + i;
        if (typeof $scope.val[parentI] !== "object") {
          $scope.val[parentI] = {};
        }

        $scope.val[parentI][i] = {
          cost: parseFloat(cost.toFixed(3)),
          cout: 0
        };

        // Раскомментить если нужно очистить поля
        //localStorage.clear(identy); 

        var local = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(identy));

        if (local) {
          if (local.cost !== $scope.val[parentI][i].cost) {
            localStorage.setItem(
              identy,
              JSON.stringify($scope.val[parentI][i])
            );
          }
          $scope.val[parentI][i].cout = local.cout;
        } else {
          localStorage.setItem(
            identy,
            JSON.stringify($scope.val[parentI][i])
          );
        }

        if (last) {
          $scope.summ = $scope.getSumm();
        }
      };

      $scope.getSumm = function() {
        var summ = 0;
        for (var i in $scope.val) {
          if ($scope.val.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            for (var j in $scope.val[i]) {
              if ($scope.val[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                summ += $scope.val[i][j].cout * $scope.val[i][j].cost;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return summ;
      };

      $scope.valChange = function(parentI, i) {
        var identy = 'Numb' + parentI + '_' + i;
        var cost = $scope.val[parentI][i].cost;
        var value = $scope.val[parentI][i].cout;

        var newValue = {
          cost: cost,
          cout: value
        };
        localStorage.setItem(identy, JSON.stringify(newValue));
        $scope.summ = $scope.getSumm();
      };


      $scope.reset = function() {
        localStorage.clear();
        var summ = 0;
        for (var i in $scope.val) {
          if ($scope.val.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            for (var j in $scope.val[i]) {
              if ($scope.val[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                $scope.val[i][j].cout = 0;
                summ = $scope.val[i][j].cout;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return summ;
      };
    });

  angular
    .module('app')
    .filter('total', function() {
      return function(result) {
        result = String(result).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ');
        return result;
      };
    });

  angular
        .module('app')
        .filter('round', function() {
            return function(result) {
                result = Math.round(result / 100) * 100;
                return result;
            };
        });

})();
```

Answer (score 2):

В контроллере добавить `$scope.all = {};`

Цены собрать в массив вот так можно

```
{{ all.total[datafields.name] = (check) ? (datafields.cost * kurs * val | number:3) : 0 }}
```

Такой способ будет собирать цены всех видов работ независимо от фильтрации, потому что при фильтрации чекбокс остается включенным.
Планкер обновил.

Comment: что-то ничего не работает, то есть не выводит сумму

Comment: Осталось прогнать массив форичем и посчитать значения цены. Данные цены привести к соответствующему типу, перед суммированием.

Comment: помоги допилить этот код, чтобы бы понять как это все работает, просто я в javascript новичок

Comment: результат попадает в массив $scope.all, с чего надо начать чтобы с ним начать работать? Например отсортировать только цифры и суммировать их